# Drop down search in Bootstrap doesn't get focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple Bootstrap menu that contains a drop down search box. This works fine when shown on a desktop but when the menu is collapsed on a mobile, and you open in, it is not possible to enter text into the search input field.

A bootply version of this problem can be found at: http://www.bootply.com/62CEZI4zNe

My code is:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-search" style="color:#AAA;"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:12px;">
            <form class="form-inline">
              <button id="searchForVenues" type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
              <input id="searchTerm" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Search" type="text">
            </form>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/browser/saved/">Saved venues</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/browser/settings/">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/browser/about/">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/auth/login/">Sign In</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p class="lead">Some text.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Can anyone point out my error and what I need to do to allow input into the search field when the menu gets collapsed on a mobile?

Comment: That `a` tag needs some sort of text content to be accessible. Use an `aria-label` attr or something like Bootstrap's `sr-only` CSS class if you don't want it to be visible. Similarly, the text input (`id="searchTerm"`) needs a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in the following lines of code:

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <button id="searchForVenues" type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        <input id="searchTerm" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Search" type="text">
  </div>
```

You were not encompassing everything in an input group. Bootstrap also says the following when using the input-group class:

```
" Instead, nest the input group inside of the form group or grid-related element."
```

Basically, you do not want to nest the input-group outside of the parameters of the form group you are currently working with (this is just an idea as to when you should use it).

Finally, here is a forked version of your **[Bootply Code](http://www.bootply.com/VK1SrOpvL6#)**

Comment: That button needs some sort of text content to be accessible. Use an `aria-label` attr or something like Bootstrap's `sr-only` CSS class if you don't want it to be visible.